# Socket.IO not working when deployed on Node/Express with React build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have setup a **Socket.io** instance inside my **Node/Express** backend. The frontend is React. Everything works fine on my device when I build the **React** app and deploy it in the backend. *However when I move the code to my production server, there is no communication whatsoever.* I believe this is because I haven't initialised the client correctly, but I have tried multiple iterations and can't get it to work.

I've tried using the server name, IP address, and localhost, but nothing works. I would expect the below to work:

```
//SOCKET.IO CLIENT SETUP
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io(); //there is NO separation between client and server in the production instance
export default socket;
```

On the server side, the code to setup the **socket.io** instance is taken straight from the **Express** example in the docs.

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();

//SOCKET.IO SERVER SETUP
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {});
httpServer.listen(8080);

//SOCKET MANAGEMENT
var connections = 0;
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  connections++;
  console.log(connections);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what has worked:

**CLIENT-SIDE: USED THE CORS OPTIONS**

```
//REPLACE 'DOMAINNAME' WITH YOUR DOMAIN/IP ADDRESS
const socket = io("http://domainname:8080", {
    withCredentials: true,
    extraHeaders: {
      "my-custom-header": "abcd"
    }
});
```

**SERVER-SIDE: ADD AN ARRAY OF ORIGINS**

As detailed in the Socket.IO docs [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/#credential-is-not-supported-if-the-cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-is-)
(It's not very clear in the docs as the example is commented out)

This means the server code is more resilient against requests originating from multiple sources.

I still don't really understand why I've had to account for CORS given that the server/client is all being served from the same place, so if anyone wants to enlighten this with an answer I will happily mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the nodejs file where the socket server created
io.attach(server);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Once you try `io` export globally

```
`io = module.exports = require("socket.io")(server, { allowEIO3: true /* false by default**/ });`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).